# Find the minimum & maximum and plot it with the mean data

Tags: plotting, maximum

Hi I have ten data set and manage to calculate the mean using them.  However I hope to find out the upper and lower limit in each point and plot it out with the mean data.
May I ask how can I calculate the upper and lower limit (minimum & maximum) of each point across the 169 x-axis data point for the y-axis and plot it together with the mean data.

Due to the text limit, I have copied the 5 data set and the mean data.

The 10 data set with the mean is shown here: [image]

What I hope to plot is shown here: [image]

Appreciate your guidance in advance. Thank you.

```
NormResC1Asc1= {0., 0.000871409, -0.000740505, -0.00134163, -0.00125942,-0.00052254, 0.00112623, 0.000823583, 0.000802469, 0.00159639,0.00448126, 0.00411105, 0.00543972, 0.00489886, 0.00384889,0.00542814, 0.00710673, 0.00598996, 0.00711033, 0.00883733, 0.00914232, 0.00852809, 0.0107261, 0.00855188, 0.00679089,0.00792223, 0.0086907, 0.00937034, 0.00964927, 0.0111331, 0.0140438,0.0199721, 0.0246155, 0.0332378, 0.051366, 0.0742839, 0.1064,0.15128, 0.201599, 0.262696, 0.329243, 0.398985, 0.465571, 0.536221, 0.609329, 0.685823, 0.761802, 0.8414, 0.911659, 0.977647, 1.04094,1.09193, 1.13431, 1.18174, 1.2516, 1.32134, 1.39694, 1.46957,1.53577, 1.60624, 1.66916, 1.70144, 1.72273, 1.74696, 1.77908, 1.814,1.85053, 1.87412, 1.90048, 1.92134, 1.93887, 1.95001, 1.96512, 1.96056, 1.96346, 1.96428, 1.95449, 1.93845, 1.9243, 1.89434, 1.87925, 1.87431,1.86644, 1.86, 1.84797, 1.82349, 1.80828, 1.79432, 1.77043, 1.72446, 1.68728, 1.64169, 1.59797, 1.5465, 1.49774,1.45594, 1.4255, 1.39835, 1.37312, 1.36832, 1.36181, 1.36442,1.35927, 1.33873, 1.31037, 1.29284, 1.26308, 1.24343, 1.21745,1.17917, 1.14398, 1.11738, 1.09264, 1.06801, 1.04273, 1.01814, 0.991142, 0.970073, 0.951085, 0.931859, 0.912559, 0.890691, 0.868159,0.85702, 0.847986, 0.843135, 0.838643, 0.832466, 0.830572, 0.826032,
0.814687, 0.808274, 0.800308, 0.790738, 0.782522, 0.769899, 0.757053,0.743036, 0.726614, 0.709825, 0.690833, 0.672784, 0.654336, 0.636639,0.625245, 0.616709, 0.607173, 0.601512, 0.596416, 0.586862, 0.576896,0.568696, 0.557097, 0.550053, 0.53843, 0.525168, 0.511005, 0.497228, 0.480725, 0.466692, 0.446603, 0.426976, 0.407396, 0.389219, 0.371394,0.353962, 0.337503, 0.321913, 0.309144}


NormResC1Asc2 = {0., -0.00463601, -0.00683428, -0.00390607, 0.000367441,0.00320625, 0.0089447, 0.0143239, 0.0218172, 0.0260871, 0.026873,0.0269342, 0.0265424, 0.0284897, 0.0282533, 0.0295213, 0.0320477,0.0345993, 0.0422748, 0.0513945, 0.0606219, 0.070095, 0.0844906,0.10046, 0.118654, 0.139828, 0.157375, 0.176484, 0.199233, 0.224248,0.25413, 0.28797, 0.325762, 0.365045, 0.408375, 0.452922, 0.496558, 0.542801, 0.584341, 0.620449, 0.652293, 0.682289, 0.713376, 0.741512, 0.76776, 0.797997, 0.830404, 0.85925, 0.888021, 0.918696, 0.945173,0.968696, 0.992999, 1.0116, 1.02261, 1.03377, 1.05325, 1.06956, 1.08246, 1.10057, 1.1215, 1.14386, 1.16751, 1.2005, 1.22458, 1.25248, 1.27889, 1.29383, 1.30232, 1.30679, 1.30262, 1.29932, 1.29325,1.28014, 1.25872, 1.24713, 1.23259, 1.22369, 1.2135, 1.1936, 1.1759,1.15637, 1.14176, 1.11292, 1.08733, 1.05505, 1.02753, 1.00353, 0.966075, 0.933721, 0.907243, 0.884606, 0.862536, 0.833083, 0.805812, 0.777462, 0.756732, 0.738711, 0.71982, 0.698264, 0.674954, 0.65101, 0.626243, 0.600121, 0.576264, 0.55032, 0.524915, 0.500051, 0.479191,0.463178, 0.450019, 0.440994, 0.431436, 0.424989, 0.420254, 0.415529, 0.410082, 0.40431, 0.400778, 0.398645, 0.394126, 0.38353, 0.371454, 0.358892, 0.347324, 0.336793, 0.324772, 0.312889, 0.300652, 0.289391, 0.280647, 0.272934, 0.263288, 0.251555, 0.239668, 0.225725, 0.214904,0.206203,0.194028, 0.17972, 0.165406, 0.153531, 0.139882, 0.128162,0.120311, 0.110714, 0.101462, 0.0909281, 0.0847471, 0.0795208,0.0734919, 0.067886, 0.0597215, 0.0512292, 0.0392019, 0.0308578,0.025025, 0.0175671, 0.0112968, 0.00525914, -0.00129158, -0.00639391, -0.00860829, -0.0091759, -0.0108808, -0.0113758, -0.0133053,-0.01256, -0.00781968}

NormResC2Asc1 = {0., -0.000413181, 0.00220723, 0.00426789, 0.00602494, 0.00677223,0.00756772, 0.0074908, 0.009106, 0.00788936, 0.00682902, 0.00611131,0.00720546, 0.0105889, 0.0141865, 0.0172424, 0.0200145, 0.0241169, 0.0288378, 0.0298885, 0.032149, 0.0340458, 0.036915, 0.0423055, 0.0495934, 0.0556933, 0.0630704, 0.0764393, 0.0883792,0.104457, 0.121796, 0.139617, 0.153674, 0.172188, 0.189452, 0.207804, 0.227732, 0.24717, 0.268627, 0.300658, 0.334622, 0.37111, 0.414429, 0.468335, 0.525668, 0.590787, 0.656239, 0.716262, 0.782697, 0.847396, 0.901097,0.947387, 0.984359, 1.01899, 1.05981, 1.10881, 1.15076, 1.19628, 1.25961,1.32766, 1.39752, 1.46449, 1.51884, 1.56601, 1.60769, 1.64225, 1.65851, 1.67623, 1.70822, 1.74614, 1.77228, 1.80287, 1.83836, 1.86757, 1.9014, 1.92114, 1.90583, 1.89246, 1.87984, 1.86693, 1.85152, 1.82916, 1.80917, 1.79047, 1.77034, 1.74984, 1.7306, 1.70442, 1.68531, 1.66426, 1.6246, 1.58603, 1.55539, 1.53111, 1.49312,1.45477, 1.4083, 1.36957, 1.33886, 1.30745, 1.27649, 1.2565, 1.23757, 1.22113, 1.19621, 1.16869, 1.14693, 1.11991, 1.08172, 1.04074, 1.00755, 0.983868, 0.962412, 0.929364, 0.899639, 0.878907, 0.859796, 0.844274, 0.824928, 0.811923, 0.808778, 0.810118, 0.808959, 0.803905, 0.801119, 0.794846, 0.789068, 0.779784, 0.770125, 0.759239, 0.754489, 0.749345, 0.7444, 0.74036, 0.732717, 0.725308, 0.716205, 0.704226, 0.692984, 0.686264, 0.677772, 0.668642, 0.661061, 0.652723, 0.644112, 0.636243, 0.618104, 0.596395, 0.575555, 0.556985, 0.538922, 0.518694, 0.497542, 0.476761, 0.457425, 0.43507, 0.404895, 0.372304, 0.340365, 0.308531, 0.283121, 0.259736, 0.23839, 0.220333, 0.20847, 0.198072, 0.188096, 0.181486, 0.173802}

NormResC2Asc2 = {0., -0.00180097, -0.00341395, -0.00382368, -0.00272602,-0.000612365, 0.00274199, 0.00763815, 0.0136091, 0.021927, 0.0256931, 0.0296957, 0.0346926, 0.0407569, 0.0482889, 0.0568951, 0.0663954,0.077136, 0.0879495, 0.09761, 0.114215, 0.132609, 0.154476, 0.179567, 0.207056, 0.23691, 0.269118, 0.302243, 0.335744, 0.373864, 0.4138,0.457747, 0.505419, 0.556849, 0.612407, 0.670161, 0.726458, 0.782978, 0.838626, 0.90159, 0.961651, 1.01454, 1.05975, 1.09749, 1.12637,1.14799, 1.17145, 1.18856, 1.20938, 1.21645, 1.22818, 1.24034, 1.25625, 1.27785, 1.30271, 1.32871, 1.34262, 1.37003, 1.39156, 1.41833, 1.44197, 1.46531, 1.48609, 1.4984, 1.50344, 1.50933, 1.52408, 1.52257, 1.51332, 1.5033, 1.49326, 1.48564, 1.47968, 1.47094, 1.45885, 1.44603, 1.43296, 1.42257, 1.4217, 1.41917, 1.41268, 1.40017, 1.37969, 1.35756, 1.34432, 1.32646, 1.3188, 1.30504, 1.28813, 1.26949, 1.24752, 1.22513, 1.20903, 1.19694, 1.17842, 1.15664, 1.12864, 1.10066, 1.06665, 1.03231, 1.00643, 
0.987499, 0.9641, 0.932407, 0.904157, 0.875443, 0.847486, 0.819754, 0.799374, 0.780295, 0.753134, 0.723853, 0.705335, 0.688429, 0.667752, 0.64974, 0.631822, 0.61565, 0.600248, 0.587094, 0.578834, 0.56959, 0.55238, 0.543133, 0.537948, 0.532455, 0.524484, 0.516743, 0.510519, 0.50274, 0.490776, 0.480955, 0.470455, 0.458677, 0.445536, 0.435461, 
0.428438, 0.42136, 0.411089, 0.399519, 0.395296, 0.388798, 0.386022, 0.378439,0.367432, 0.353752, 0.338541, 0.324606, 0.312696, 0.29831, 0.281731, 0.262983, 0.240594,0.218871, 0.197334, 0.177187, 0.15666, 0.133291, 0.109128, 0.0887236, 0.0663095, 0.0467393, 0.0307616,0.0180294, 0.00891356, 0.00138757, -0.00392717, -0.00514167,-0.00684054}

NormResC3Asc1 = {0., -0.0000976144, -0.00138466, 0.000125477, -0.00110893, -0.00498112, -0.00630241, -0.00657901, -0.00725159, -0.00659388, -0.00659845, -0.00706664, -0.00344941, 0.000137614, -0.000387347, -0.00157237, -0.00198071, -0.00237189, 0.000114635, -0.000107643,0.00022374, 0.00119657, 0.00432338, 0.0138035, 0.0237471, 0.0376243,0.0612806, 0.0906647, 0.125037, 0.163707, 0.205993, 0.249953, 0.292807, 0.336476, 0.38086, 0.433269, 0.504326, 0.578607, 0.647526, 0.7227, 0.799546, 0.873147, 0.937212, 1.00803, 1.0565, 1.10902, 1.16767, 1.23609, 1.30932, 1.39061, 1.46186, 1.52139, 1.56786, 1.61008, 1.63795, 1.65023, 1.66676, 1.68952, 1.70435, 1.72628, 1.74464, 1.76816, 1.79682, 1.82674, 1.84781, 1.86035, 1.87055, 1.87202, 1.87325, 1.87508, 1.86443, 1.83826, 1.81371, 1.79, 1.76717,1.74894, 1.72948, 1.71585, 1.70227, 1.69761, 1.69419, 1.67621, 1.67035, 1.66915, 1.66739, 1.65671, 1.64023, 1.61476, 1.59472, 1.57357, 1.5439, 1.51028, 1.47312, 1.4384, 1.41298, 1.39654, 1.37713, 1.35854, 1.33796, 1.31771, 1.30083, 1.28977, 1.2879, 1.27921,1.26411, 1.24272, 1.2206, 1.20104, 1.18487, 1.15557, 1.12451, 1.09713, 1.06708, 1.05697, 1.0351, 1.0116, 0.987836, 0.969216, 0.945689, 0.924778, 0.909043, 0.890332, 0.869609, 0.855697, 0.848319, 0.842844, 0.841775, 0.840414, 0.837422, 0.831816, 0.830728, 0.825025, 0.818163, 0.804716, 0.794514, 0.778744, 0.765805, 0.758654, 0.748897, 0.741155, 0.732674, 0.722828, 0.714738, 0.708399, 0.698852, 0.686646, 0.674559, 0.659415, 0.641569, 0.629899, 0.614431, 0.599586, 0.585799, 0.57314, 0.558917, 0.542506, 0.525706, 0.51134, 0.492637, 0.469155, 0.447409, 0.425851, 0.400172, 0.38076, 0.359757, 0.336593, 0.31288, 0.296651, 0.277142}

MeanAsc3KB={0., -0.00149155, -0.00328155, -0.00418532, -0.00394429, -0.00369898, -0.00287763, -0.00137433, 0.00102372, 0.00312159, 0.0052537, 0.00721931, 0.0103163, 0.0134289, 0.0158912, 0.0199582, 0.0258992, 0.0327605, 0.0413554, 0.0488193, 0.0581396, 0.0696336, 0.0829017, 0.097421, 0.112886, 0.131179, 0.150935, 0.174114, 0.200447, 0.22947, 0.261125, 0.294155, 0.327842, 0.364596, 0.403675, 0.445356, 0.489888, 0.538389, 0.589033, 0.643937, 0.699853, 0.753173, 0.803598, 0.855487, 0.903845, 0.951597, 0.997245, 1.03717, 1.07802, 1.11942, 1.16096,1.19962, 1.23565, 1.26847, 1.29812, 1.32617, 1.35227, 1.37724,1.39991, 1.42354, 1.44402, 1.46178, 1.47228, 1.48227, 1.48872, 1.49788, 1.50424, 1.50411, 1.50425, 1.5026, 1.49949, 1.49516, 1.4906, 1.48372, 1.47592, 1.46565, 1.4491, 1.43243, 1.41546, 1.39649, 1.37763, 1.35683, 1.33759, 1.31884, 1.30022, 1.27891, 1.26108, 1.24074, 1.21753, 1.19404, 1.17071, 1.14705, 1.12232, 1.09802, 1.07298, 1.04906, 1.02485, 1.00201, 0.97755, 0.956764, 0.93663, 0.921437, 0.905122, 0.886437, 0.86752, 0.848775, 0.83049, 0.81443,0.799423, 0.78164, 0.763705, 0.746549, 0.729123, 0.712411, 0.698305, 0.685914, 0.672164, 0.661874, 0.6526, 0.642622, 0.633615, 0.624053, 0.612424, 0.603154, 0.594537, 0.58671, 0.580103, 0.573262, 0.565826,0.558162, 0.550711, 0.542961, 0.535223, 0.526018, 0.517049, 0.504237, 0.492761, 0.481464, 0.471004, 0.460619, 0.450575, 0.440173, 0.428631, 0.417516, 0.406721, 0.394904, 0.381238, 0.367534, 0.353286, 0.338529, 0.322757, 0.305822, 0.287322, 0.269068, 0.250637, 0.233045, 0.216088, 0.1991, 0.182598, 0.168509, 0.155132, 0.143186, 0.13258, 0.124667,0.118874, 0.112319, 0.10568, 0.100593}
```

Answer (score 7):

[`Transpose`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html) all of the data lists

```
trans = Transpose[{NormResC1Asc1, NormResC1Asc2, NormResC2Asc1, 
     NormResC2Asc2, NormResC3Asc1}];
```

[`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) the functions {[`Max`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Max.html), [`Mean`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mean.html), [`Min`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Min.html)} onto the transposed lists.

```
{max, mean, min} = # /@ trans & /@ {Max, Mean, Min};
```

Plot

```
ListLinePlot[{max, mean, min},
 PlotLegends -> {Max, Mean, Min}]
```

[image]

Comment: A minor variation: `{max, mean, min} = Transpose[Through[{Min, Mean, Max}[#]] & /@ trans];`

Comment: Thank you! @Bob