# General Trend of a ListLogLinearPlot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, mathematical-optimization, logarithmic-scale, maximum

I have a [data file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12UAE83LI6T6xbSqRO9hrWJCYcJzD6Z40/view?usp=sharing).

I must plot this using `ListLogLinearPlot` and identify the trend (or the mean). Below is my code for Importing the data file and plotting it.

```
d = Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "TEST1.dat"];
ListLogLinearPlot[d, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

I have followed the examples in the [Documentation](https://wolfram.com/xid/0d6emfb7ca-wxgjw) and an [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/266594/84456), here, given by [@Bob Hanlon](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9362/bob-hanlon) to produce my desired graph.

- However, I failed miserably.

The codes for the two methods with the unwanted graphs are shown below.

### Method-1

```
filtered1 = MeanFilter[d, 50];
filtered2 = MedianFilter[d, 50];
filtered3 = MaxFilter[d, 10];

ListLogLinearPlot[{d, filtered1, filtered2, filtered3}]
```

[image]

### Method-2

```
{max, mean, min} = # /@ d & /@ {Max, Mean, Min};

ListLogLinearPlot[{d, max, mean, min}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

---

**I need a plot that should, more or less, look like this:**

[image]

***How do I achieve my desired result? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not using the filters correctly. You should apply them only to the $y$ values, but when you do `MeanFilter[d, 50]`, the filter is applied also to the $x$ values.

An elegant way is to use [`TimeSeries`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeries.html), which `*Filter` functions recognize and are correctly applied only to the $y$ values.

```
ts = TimeSeries[d];
filtered1 = MeanFilter[ts, 50];
filtered2 = MedianFilter[ts, 50];
filtered3 = MaxFilter[ts, 10];

ListLogLinearPlot[{ts, filtered1, filtered2, filtered3}, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank yo for pointing out my mistake. :)